# How can I join together multiple VOB files?

Tags: video, dvd, conversion

When I ripped a DVD using [dvd::rip](http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/), the main title was split into several 1GB VOB files. How can I join them to make a single VOB file that contains the whole title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a .VOB container file is, by definition of the [DVD specification](http://www.mpeg.org/MPEG/DVD/File/File.html), limited to **1 GByte** (1048 MB).

If we need a file that contains a whole movie, then we need to convert these files to  another [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) (e.g. xvid, MKV, plain MPEG etc.), e.g. by using [ffmpeg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/ffmpeg.1.html):

> `ffmpeg -i snatch_1.vob -f avi -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k -g 300 -bf 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k snatch.avi`
>   <sup>(from [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/ffmpeg.1.html))</sup>

[Concatenating](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC27) video files can only be done with some formats (e.g. MPEG).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the video_ts folder with terminal.
For example /Videos/DVD/VIDEO_TS
cat VTS_01_1.VOB VTS_01_2.VOB VTS_01_3.VOB > ../Your_Joined_File.VOB

Your joined file is on folder /Videos/DVD